# Python Code in a JavaScript running on a Cloudflare Worker

Tags: javascript, python, html, svg, cloudflare-workers

I am building a worker that displays an `svg` file that is generated using a python code `triangles.py`. In this python code, I have a function:

```py
getSVGCode(vw, vh):
    ⋮
    callingOtherFunction(inThisFile)
    ⋮
    return svgCode
```

This function needs to be called from a javascript that is running on Cloudflare Workers (using their method given below). The svgCode is inserted into the `html` string that the javascript returns to the browser.

```js
const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>

  <svg>My svg here</svg>

  <p>This markup was generated by a Cloudflare Worker.</p>
</body>`

async function handleRequest(request) {
  return new Response(html, {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8",
    },
  })
}

addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  return event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
```

So, I want to know a way to get the Javascript code to pass the viewport dimensions (`vh` and `vw`) to the python function so that the svg can be generated using this size. If this option is not possible, I will have to resize the svg which can look stretched. I also want to know how to make the Worker run the python code from javascript too.

I am a beginner at coding, and javascript especially. Please include full information so that I can understand your answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured I can use `<script></script>` inside the `html` variable. I used something like the following.

```html
<script>
    const vw = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    const vh = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var svgHref = "https://your.url.here/using?height=vh&ampwidth=vw";
    document.getElementById("triangles-svg").src = svgHref;
</script>
```

This was accompanied by a body with,

```html
<body>
    <img id="triangles-svg">
</body>
```

Viola. :)